# Get process owner from its code object on macOS

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

On macOS, how can I know the owner of a process at runtime, for which I have access to its [code object](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/seccode)?

In Apple's words, the code object is:

> A code object representing signed code running on the system.

It would seem reasonable to think I can infer its pid, owner, etc, since it's code currently running, but I haven't been able to find how. In the options of [information I can retrieve,](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/seccsflags) I do not find these.

Comment: SecCode doesn't have to refer to a process. It can be lots of things. "In addition to UNIX processes, these elements can include scripts, applets, widgets, and so forth." There may be no owner; the code may exist somewhere but not be running. If the code object is shared, there may be many owners simultaneously. Where are you getting the SecCode from?

Comment: Yes, I saw this, but I am interested in getting it when I can. I get it from NetworkExtension, NEFilterDataProvider, NEFilterFlow property: [sourceAppAuditToken](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nefilterflow)

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to correlate this to a specific process owner. That audit token may not be associated with a unique process. You can use it to create a SecTask, that correlates to a mach message, not a process.

Comment: You can use that to find the bundle identifier, and you could use that to track back through RunningProcesses. But that may not map uniquely.